# perl test content to see if contains HTML

Tags: html, perl, contains

I would like to test content that is submitted by users to see if contains HTML or not, and I'd prefer to do it without having to write my own regex. Does anyone know of a module that does this or a good way to do this in perl?

Comment: You should check for `<` and `>` characters. `if ($content =~ /[<>]/) { .. }`

Comment: @mpapec - What if there was the following text in the submitted content: "1 < 2 and 3 > 2"?

Comment: May I ask why you want to know?

Comment: It's still html, not valid though. :) I would take a look at http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTML-Parser-3.71/lib/HTML/Entities.pm

Comment: looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [HTML::Restrict](http://search.cpan.org/~oalders/HTML-Restrict-2.1.6/lib/HTML/Restrict.pm) module what allows restrict the content only to allowed tags.

Example:

```
use 5.012;
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Restrict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @texts = map { { "has_html", 0, "text", $_ } }
            split(/==cut-here==/, do{ local $/; <DATA> });

my $res = HTML::Restrict->new();

foreach my $text (@texts) {
    my $tmp = $text->{text};
    my $plain = $res->process($tmp);
    $plain =~ s/\s//gs;
    $tmp =~ s/\s//gs;
    $text->{has_html} = $tmp cmp $plain ? "YES" : "NO";
}
say Dumper(\@texts);

__DATA__

    <img src="image.jpg" alt="tricky>text" />

    text with html
==cut-here==

plain

text here

==cut-here==again <!-- a > b --> with html==cut-here==
plain
```

will check 4 chunks of text and detect for html. If you configure the `HTML::Restrict` you can check with "allowed" and "not allowed" HTML tags too.

Comment: well that removes the HTML, but I just need to know if the content contains HTML. I've tried comparing the content before I put it through HTML::Restrict and after, but HTML::Restrict will also remove trailing new lines, so that presents an issue because it could say the before and after were not equal (implying there was HTML removed), when really there was just an extra new line

Comment: @srchulo you can remove all white spaces from both and compare after. If they're identical - doesn't contain HTML. Edited the example.